# Array variable inside DB::raw query laravel

Tags: sql, database, laravel

I want to predifine **$processingStatus** array and use it inside Laravel DB::raw query but this gives me the following error-

**Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax**

My query is a large one so I am only pasting the fragment which I guess is causing the error-

`DB::raw("COUNT(CASE WHEN (status_change_log.status in $processingStatus) THEN 1 END) AS processing")`

My processingStatus variable contains **[0 => "S2",  1 => "S13",  2 => "S21"]**

Anyone help me out with proper format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Concatenate the string with the php variable

```php
DB::raw("COUNT(CASE WHEN (status_change_log.status in ".$processingStatus.") THEN 1 END) AS processing")
```

Comment: This doesnt work as it gives `Array to string conversion` error.

Comment: that means the ```$processingStatus``` variable is an Array, could you give me more info on what you need from that variable? what field, or print in console that variable, so you see what is it, you need it to be a string to use that value in an SQL statement.

Comment: Yes of course. There are some status stored in that variable and the query has to run dynamically. Thats why I have to use a variable. I have edited my qstn and mentioned the elements of the array. Hope that helps.

Comment: I needed to convert the array to string and after that it worked. Thanks for your suggestion.